# Google apps script in google site wants authorisation

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently reading a book: "Google Script: Enterprise application essentials"

In the first chapter there is an exercise that adds a Google Apps Script Gadget to a page of a Google Site. I followed the guidelines but when I load that page the widget wants Authorisation before it will work.

I don't want that to happen. Is it normal? Can it be fixed? Why is it shown?

The gadget itself consists of a basic GUI with just a label on in and in the code:

```
    function doGet(e) {
          var appl = UiApp.createApplication();
          appl.add(appl.loadComponent("MyGui")); // name of the saved Gui  
          return appl;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deployed as a web app, if you chose the app to run as the user executing the app, then authorization will be requested from the end user. This is logical since the end user must know what resources the app has access to.

If you do not want to access any of the end user's resources, then you can set the app to run as you and the end user won't be shown the authorization method.